# ECHO post data from AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to echo the post data i get using AJAX-JQUERY.

I have a dropdown in that dropdown i show some values from database.
Now the item i select frmo dropdown is sent as POST to my controller.

If i open my network tab in browser, i can see the POST data i get using my AJAX script.

Like this:
[image: response]

But if i try to echo it shows me nothing on browser.

I am using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
      var site = this.id;
      var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 

       //get value for throw to controller

      $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST", //send with post 
          url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
          data: {site:site}, 
          success:function(data){ 

          },

      });
  });
```

The DROPDOWN:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php
      foreach($sites as $site)
      {
        echo "<li class='specialLink' id='".$site->site_key."'><a href='#'>".$site->site_key."</a></li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**THE PHP SCRIPT**

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: your php code doesn't seem to REQUEST any data

Comment: @Lakshya if i do var_dump($_REQUEST) i get nothing. So how should i be printing the POST data then?

Comment: where is your controller (the PHP script you are posting to)?

Comment: @low_rents var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);

Comment: use `console.log` in SUCESS function and print the message then it will show you the data what is sent by that

Comment: in PHP use `var_dump($_REQUEST['url']);` or what ever you want to see exactly

Comment: @Lakshya i did console.log(); but still no data on screen i did var_dump($_request);

Comment: var_dump($_POST['site']);

Comment: @RK12 Message: Undefined index: site

Comment: so simple then the `site:site` is going empty see your code again your `var=site` must be empty

Comment: then why does it show in my network tab?? XHR data shows me the item i select @Lakshya

Comment: if i echo my `$_POST` I just get `Array` in my response-tab. and you are getting nothing Rajan?

Comment: var test  = "test"; then pass this {test:test} and chack echo $_POST['test'];
for checking data is passing or not by ajax call

Comment: if `site` is showing undefined index error then it is sure a array is going to next page you can try sending one variable

Comment: i am not sure what you want to achieve, Rajan - but try this in your php controller-script: `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: @Lakshya also console shows me this <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
 <b>array</b> <i>(size=2)</i>
   '/customer/dashboard/index' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
   'site' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'54th-65hy'</font> <i>(length=9)</i>
 </pre>

Comment: its written there that array is coming to your page use `json_encode($_POST['site']);`

Comment: then it shows me Message: Undefined index: site

Comment: Try this and tell what is the result :
$your_array = !empty($_POST['site']) ? json_decode($_POST['site']) : "empty";
var_dump($your_array);

Comment: @RK12 error solved but no data on screen

Comment: Try this :
$your_array = !empty($_POST['site']) ? $_POST['site'] : "empty"; 

var_dump($your_array);

Comment: Something wrong in ajax call i think. Please try this : alert(site); return false;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105130/discussion-between-rajan-and-rk12).

Comment: Hi, does the script return anything as you remove the line var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; before your ajax call?

Comment: I will try this once I reach office tomorrow, for now m on mobile so can't check @Sebastian Krysiak

Comment: And I guess it will not return anything before Ajax call if I remove that line because after that line if I do console.log('site'); I get the item selected in browser console

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak if i remove that line then also i get the response in my console and network tab

Comment: so as You success:function(data){ alert(data); } you have what you wanted and now you need to pass it somewhere with ur javascript right? It's not like you want to echo the recieved values with php?

Comment: I want to echo the item i select using PHP but m not sure where i am wrong @SebastianKrysiak

Answer (score 3):

> But if i try to echo it shows me nothing on browser

That is because you are making the request using Ajax instead of just loading it in the main window.

If you want to load the content in the main window, then just submit a regular form. If you *must* use JavaScript, then you can generate the form using DOM methods, add it to the page, then call its `submit()` method.

(That said, you seem to be trying to simulate links, which would make a GET request more appropriate than a POST request and allow you to just use a regular link (or set `location.href = ...` if you must use JS, which you really shouldn't need to for this).
If you want to use Ajax then you need to change this:

> ```
> success:function(data){ 
>
> },
> ```

… so that you actually do something with the value of `data` (such as add it to the DOM of the current page).

Comment: the dropdown here i bootstrap dropdown in <li> tag there is no form so how do i submit data ?

Comment: You add a form. Either by editing the HTML directly or by generating one with JavaScript.

Comment: this dropdown i am having is in bootrsap navbar, if i add a form tag and then dropdown values then the loop of navbar if affected

Answer (score 0):

Please send data in this form in ajax call

```
data : {"site" : site};
```

key should be the string and then it's value in js variable.

Comment: No. In a JavaScript object literal the property name can be represented by either a string or an identifier. Making that change will have no significant effect.

Comment: @Rk how should i be printing ?

Comment: you should get all the data concatinated in a string and echo that in the php file and you will get it as a response in ajax success file. put it in the HTML you want using jquery $('#<id of the HTML tag>').html(output);